# On iPhone 6 (and probably others) my simple HTML emails are display with stupidly large font

Tags: iphone, html-email

I have a little application for a customer which sends some confirmation and info mails. This all works pretty good. However, when I view such an email on an iPhone it looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGyvo.png

I have tried it as follows, because this bring iphones safari, to not mess with the font. In the email (which on android devices looks beautiful) this won't work, somehow.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    body, p{
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
</style>
<body>
<font face="arial" size="10px">
<%=in.temp.str7%>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the viewport scale might help.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: thanks ;) however, you have initial-scale set while @Gortonington hasn't. instead he sets min and max? what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

to head tag and moving the `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`to inline inside the body tag and font tag like so - `<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">` or heck do both and keep it in the header too.

Honestly the issue may come from other stylings or elements in your html affecting the scale (hopefully solved with viewport) so please keep in mind if you are importing content into this template from an outside source, it may be retaining styling that can affect how it is rendered.

Comment: thank you for that. i will try it right away. in between the body tag there only come some p tags and text, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

You led the right way, but your tips alone did not work. I now have added a doctype and cleaned up everything a bit. I also got rid of the font tag (which, as I found out, is not supported in html 5 anymore).
Anyway, I do not know, what exactly solved the problem, but this is certainly a good base and working fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <style>
        body{
            font-family: Arial,​Helvetica,​ sans-serif !important;
            font-size: 14px !important;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
        }
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <%=in.temp.str7%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although many would disagree, declaring Doctype always is helpful. But I would probably recommend: "XHTML 1.0 Transitional". It seems to be more consistent across browsers. HTML 5 doctype is not supported universally as of yet. Honestly it was probably the removal of the font tag as well as the declared font family and size for body. I would just recommend moving it inline so that gmail app, etc don't strip it out and insert defaults.